# Mixed authentication with WIF for multiple endpoints in a Windows service

Tags: wcf, wif

We need to expose two WCF endpoints in a single Windows service. One endpoint should use claims based authentication (WIF), with the other using certificate authentication. Unfortunately all our attempts have failed because WIF configuration attaches to all WCF endpoints; the endpoint which should use certificate authentication requires a token.

I can’t find any solution to this particular issue. Is it possible to expose two endpoints within one windows service with two different authentication where only one of them is WIF, and if it’s possible, then how?

Answer (score 1):

Read
[How to mix WIF and non-WIF endpoints in a single WCF <service>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281013/how-to-mix-wif-and-non-wif-endpoints-in-a-single-wcf-service)

There is no way to do it unless you use two different service contracts (this could be just marker interfaces though) or you do things manually without WCF (i.e.: create your own behavior and claims authorization manager using WIF). It's not that hard, but you need to understand how things work.